# Convert BASH Array to JSON Array

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, sh

I have a BASH Array as follows:

```
TEMPARRAY=( "1 A" "2 B" )
```

I want this array to convert to JSON Array (or Key Value Pair ?), like this:

```
{
  "Comment": "MX Record for XYZ",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "CREATE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "XYZ",
        "Type": "MX",
        "TTL": 300,
        "ResourceRecords": [
        {
          "Value": "1 A"
        },
        {
          "Value": "2 B"
        }
       ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**USE CASE:** I am creating a shell script to add AWS Route53 DNS Records and I am stuck at specifying multiple values for MX records. If I update the MX records, it get replaced with a newer one.

Sample Code from my script:

```
      if [[ "$MXCOUNT" -gt "1" ]]; then
        TEMPARRAY=( "$(grep -i MX  "$DNSFILE" | cut -d, -f3)" )
        for i in "${TEMPARRAY[@]}"; do
         # POSSIBLE CODE HERE
        done
      else
        addMXrecord  "$DNSNAME" "$DNSVALUE"
      fi
```

The function **addMXrecord** will be containing the JSON (although it's for a single MX record.)

DNSFILE is in format:

```
DOMAIN,MX,1 A
DOMAIN,MX,2 B
```

Happy to provide anymore information.

Comment: There's more content in your proposed output file than there is in your input file. One can't very well manufacture data out of nothing.

Comment: ...that said, the general-purpose tool for this kind of operation (the accepted toolkit for JSON operations in shell, much as awk is for manipulation of line- and field-oriented files) is [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

Comment: BTW, an answer to the literal question from the title (before getting into the weeds with question-specific details) looks like this: `jq -cRn '[inputs]' < <( (( ${#array[@]} )) && printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}")`

Comment: ...that said, since you want to parse a bunch of details out of your input, getting into the weeds *would* be necessary for a proper answer, and I don't have the time right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't sound like something you'd want to implement in Bash, to be honest!

Either way, if you already have most of your script implemented in Bash, you could use a tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), or if you don't want the additional dependency, you could "shell out" to, for instance, Python:

```
python -c 'import json, sys; print(json.dumps([{"Value": v} for v in sys.argv[1:]]))' foo bar
```

will output

```
[{"Value": "foo"}, {"Value": "bar"}]
```

which you can embed elsewhere.

Comment: This is the output I am looking for, and can replace this in the script. However, I tried with jq and no luck so far (even googled for syntax). Any help for this in bash ?

Comment: your python command works, will have to work with this as of now, until I figure something in BASH. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A `jq` filter for this would look like

```
TEMPARRAY=( "1 A" "2 B" )
printf '%s\n' "${TEMPARRAY[@]}" |
  jq --slurp -R '
    split("\n")[:-1] | map({Value: .}) |
    {
      Comment: "MX Record for XYZ",
      Changes: [
        {
          Action: "CREATE",
          ResourceRecordSet: {
            Name: "XYZ",
            Type: "MX",
            TTL: 300,
            ResourceRecords: .
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  '
```

`split` takes input lines and creates an array `["1 A", "2 B", ""]` (the `[:-1]` gets rid of the final empty element due to the trailing newline from the input). `map` produces a corresponding array of objects `[{"Value": "1 A"}, {"Value": "2 B"}]`. The rest is just the template into which this array is inserted, as the value (represented by `.`, the input from `map`) to associate with the key `ResourceRecords`.